# Rails 3 : Generate view using rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json, rabl

In my Rails Application i have Two instance variables @departments and @register

@departments =

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "departmentid": "DP11"
        },
        {
            "departmentid": "DP12"
        },
        {
            "departmentid": "DP13"
        },
        {
            "departmentid": "DP10"
        }
    ]
}
```

@register =

```
{
    "attendance": [
        0,
        0,
        2,
        1
    ]
}
```

@register contains an array .

Is it possible to show like below format using rabl (attendancebydepartment.json.rabl) view

```
{
        "users": [
            {
                "departmentid": "DP11",
                "attendance"=0
            },
            {
                "departmentid": "DP12",
                "attendance"=0
            },
            {
                "departmentid": "DP13",
                "attendance"=2
            },
            {
                "departmentid": "DP10",
                "attendance"=1
            }
        ]
    }
```

My controller looks like

```
def attendancebydepartment
    @register = Array.new
    @departments = User.select('departmentid').uniq
    startdate = params[:startdate]
    enddate = params[:enddate]
    @count = @departments.count
    @departments.each do |d|
    @register << (Register.where(:date => startdate..enddate , :departmentid => d.departmentid).sum(:one))+(Register.where(:date => startdate..enddate , :departmentid => d.departmentid).sum(:two))
    end
  end
```

Is it possible to add each department and its corresponding attendance to array,so that i can display like expected format.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the `zip` method to create a new variable and then present that.

```
irb(main):001:0> departments = {'users' => [{'id' => 1}, {'id' => 2}]}
=> {"users"=>[{"id"=>1}, {"id"=>2}]}

irb(main):002:0> register = {'attendance' => [0,1]}
=> {"attendance"=>[0, 1]}

irb(main):004:0> departments['users'].zip(register['attendance'])
=> [[{"id"=>1}, 0], [{"id"=>2}, 1]]
```

On the other hand, it looks like a simpler design would be to have a `Department` model that has a `has_many` association with `Users`. Then you could refer to the count of users directly from an instance of `Department`.

Comment: department is not a model ,it is a field in User table .There is no relation between User and Register.......

Answer (score 0):

It may be easiest to create objects in your controller using `OpenStruct`, something like this, but I would recommend re-writting `attendancebydepartment` to not loop twice.

```
@users = []
@departments.each_with_index do |dep, index|      
  user = OpenStruct.new
  user.departmentid = dep.departmentid
  user.attendence = @register[index].attendence
  @users << user
end
```

And in the view:

```
collection @users => :users
attribute :departmentid, :attendence
```

Comment: i am getting an error " MultiJson::DecodeError - invalid format, expected , or } while in an object at line 3, column 2"......